# Show the following Inner product problem

Tags: inner-products, orthogonality

Im stuck in this problem it seems easy but I can't find the way to show it

Show that $y \perp x_n $ and $x_n \to x$ together imply $x \perp y$

Thanks for you time.

Comment: Hint: Inner product should be a continuous function on the space you are considering, so you should be able to interchange the limit and the function argument (i.e., $\langle y , x \rangle = \langle y , \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n \rangle = \lim \langle y , x_n \rangle$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $\langle y, x_n \rangle = 0$ for all $n$ and the function $z \mapsto \langle y, z \rangle$ is continuous, hence $\langle y, x_n \rangle \to \langle y, x \rangle$, hence $\langle y, x \rangle = 0$.

Another (essentially equivalent) way of looking at it is to let $S = \{ z | \langle y, z \rangle = 0 \}$
and notice that $S$ is closed because it is the inverse image of the closed
set $\{0\}$ under the continuous map $z \mapsto \langle y, z \rangle$.
Then since $x_n \in S$, $x_n \to x$ and $S$ is closed, we have $x \in S$.